# Encrypt in C++ and decrypt in C#

Tags: c#, c++, encryption

I have to encrypt a field in C++ application and decrypt it back in C#.
For encryption, i am using openssl library. The code is as follows -

```
  AES_KEY AESkey;
  string plainText = "kumar atul" ;
  unsigned char CBlock[1024]={0};
  unsigned char Key[16];

  char *MBlock = new char(plainText.size() ) ;
  int pLen = plainText.size();

  int plainTextLen=strlen((const char*) MBlock);
  strcpy((char *) MBlock, plainText.c_str() );
  for (int i=strlen((const char*) MBlock); i<16; i++)
  {
    MBlock[i] = 0;
  }
  unsigned char ckey[] =  { 200, 5, 78, 232, 9, 6, 0, 4, 200, 5, 78, 232, 9, 6, 0, 4 };
  AES_set_encrypt_key((const unsigned char *) ckey, 128, &AESkey);
  unsigned char ivec[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
  int num = 0 ;
  AES_cfb128_encrypt( (const unsigned char *) MBlock, CBlock, 16, &AESkey, ivec, &num, AES_ENCRYPT) ;
  std::string str(( char *) CBlock);
```

I wrote some programs in C# to encrypt the same string to same encrypted value, but they didn't work.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1 :

I couldn't find the way to encrypt in base64 encoding in c++.
Also,

C# code to encrypt :

```
        private byte[] DESKey = { 200, 5, 78, 232, 9, 6, 0, 4, 200, 5, 78, 232, 9, 6, 0, 4 };
        private byte[] DESInitializationVector = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };


        public  string Encrypt(string value)
        {            
            using (var cryptoProvider = new AesManaged())
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, cryptoProvider.CreateEncryptor(DESKey, DESInitializationVector), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream))
            {
                writer.Write(value);
                writer.Flush();
                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                writer.Flush();
                return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);
            }
        }
```

Comment: In order for someone to help you, you should also show the C# part of the code.

Comment: Hi @HABJAN, thanks, I have added the c# code. Also, i wish i could encrypt in both to base64 encoding.

Comment: You're using CFB mode in C++, but the default (CBC) mode in C#. You'll need to change to using CBC mode in C++, as `AesManaged` doesn't support CFB mode.

Comment: @Iridium, thanks... i tried -- ` AES_cbc_encrypt( MBlock, CBlock, 20, &AESkey, ivec, AES_ENCRYPT) ; `  -- but it didn't give same result. I must be missing something.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @hoetz hi, yes the issue was different encryption modes used. I rectified them and it worked. Not working on that project anymore so I don't remember the exact modes used. :)

Comment: FWIW here's how we did it: https://gist.github.com/hoetz/e6c271abffc5372acf95332c68d8d8a1